# Python - TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, tuples

When I write this program it gives me this error. Why?

```
n = []
for x range(1500, 2701):
    if(x % 7 == 0) and (x % 5== 0):
        n.append(str(x))
print(",".join(n))

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: you are missing `in` in the `for`: `for x in range...` - but that causes a different exception. Are you sure this is the code you are running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
n = []
for x in range(1500, 2701):
    if x % 7 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
        n.append(str(x))
print(",".join(n))
```

- you don't need brackets in the If statement
- in is missing in for..in

Comment: best to wait with answering until further clarification - reported error is not caused by the missing `in`...

Comment: @GiladGreen this works fine in Python 3.7, then I think issue is solved, so I posted it

Comment: well exactly! as the question states a different error then either the posted code is not the intended code or there is no problem to solve..